# When writing an item database which is more useful scriptable objects or XML / JSON

Tags: json, xml, unity-game-engine, database-design

Everybody I have been playing with the idea of creating an item database. The question I have is which would be more useful and intuitive to use? If you guys have a pros-and-cons list for either of them throw them at me.

Thanks,
Jared

Comment: It depends on what you are saving to the database. If you are saving an item prefab, you would need to use SO since you can't save a game object to XML or JSON. However, if it is just basic datatypes XML/JSON would be a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ScriptableObjects you get the inspector for free. It's also the Unity endorsed way to do things. You can include references to other ScriptableObjects and game specific data. Other GameObjects can reference the ScriptableObject themselves. They can even contain bits of code.

A database is overblown for this. Even if you might need one later, start with the simple thing. Other options here are a serialized Dictionary or a directory structure. But start simple first.